# Android pagination for LinearLayout

Tags: android, pagination, android-linearlayout

I want to create Android pagination with previous and next button, but without using `ListView`.

Here i'm using a `ScrollView` inside that one parent `LinearLayout` (with *Vertical orientation*) and inside that some child `LinearLayout`'s.

How can i implement pagination for `LinearLayout`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). It's the best way for pagination in Android.